# how to check if key and value already exists in hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
public static Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

public static DateTime LoggedOn = DateTime.Now;

ht.Add(message, LoggedOn);//message contains different sting messages for my logfile
```

Now i want to check  if particular message exists and Time also.
For example i have done

```
bool keyexists = ht.ContainsKey(message);

bool valueexists = ht.ContainsValue(LoggedOn);
```

it will return true because i have added it to hastable now i want to check if it is added more than one time then do something ..how can i show something like that??

Answer (score 0):

**I did something like:**

```
  bool exists = hash.Count(x => x.key == /* value to compare if exists*/) == 0 ? false : true

  hash.ContainsKey(/* value to compare if exists*/)) 
  hash["c"] == /* value to compare if exists*/);
```

example from Dictonary but will also work for Hashtable